# how to combine strategy and mvc pattern

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, uml, software-design, class-diagram

I'm trying to made my project class diagram diagram. In my project, text contents are converted to visuals, i had used strategy and factory pattern for visuals, but currently i'm using php code igniter at server end and i'm not very much aware of mvc pattern in class diagram. so my question is how can i combine them?[image]

Edit: IVisual is used here for strategic pattern (TimeLine, GeoLocation, Relationship sheet are all strategies), and VisualFactory is used as factory class which creates any type of visual.

Comment: requirement is not clear. If you clarify then it will be helpful. specially explain "i had used strategy and factory pattern for visuals" this line.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is designed to separate your concerns between your model(data), your view(html rendered) and your controller (the request/response engine, in your case php controllers).

Your view will contain all the classes that carry your data, for example you will need one or many classes that carry the geolocation of Country XYZ is Latitude:XX and Longitude:YY

Your controller is simply the gateway between your model and your view. for example, the controller will receive a request to http://myapp.com/page1, then the controller connects with the database, brings a model with it and passes it to the view, then the view will recognize that you need to represent the geolocation data and will render the html.

MVC is in a higher hierarchy of software design, usually is embedded in the framework that you use

hope it helps,

Comment: It means that Visual Factory should have association with View only, and text (from which visuals are generated) should have association with model?

Comment: mmmh, the view should only consist of classes related to the rendering, for example html files and pictures and simple classes (similar to DTOs data-transfer-objects). If your classes are generating, retrieving or storing data, they should go to the model. And if your classes are responding directly to the user, they should be in the controller. Not everything is black and white, but that should give you some guidance, hope it helps

Comment: -1 : controller is not between model and view, model is not "data", view is not responsible for rendering html .. and none of this helps in any way

Comment: would you like to give your own interpretation of MVC then?, maybe we all can learn. I never said that model is data, I said they were classes that carry data, the controller is between model and view in the framework, even though is the first layer the user interacts with. And the View IS the responsible for rendering

Comment: @tereško I also would like to see your point of view. We all can learn :-)